# Can a rocker switch with two positions be an SPDT?

Tags: switches

I have rocker switches that look very similar to this:

[image: my rocker switch]

In my current understanding, a 2-positions rocker is meant to be an SPST, and a 3-positions rocker (see below) is meant to be an SPDT:

[image]

From [this source](https://learn.sparkfun.com/tutorials/switch-basics), I find the following image showing an SPST rocker switch:

[image: spst rocker switch]

I observe here that it has only two pins. The 3-pins switch they have is actually an SPDT looking like so:

[image: SPDT switch]

On [this source](http://www.learningaboutelectronics.com/Articles/SPST-rocker-switch-wiring.php), they show how to wire a rocker switch, like so:

[image: rocker internals]
[image: Wiring a rocker switch]

I have a few questions coming from this:

1. Why do they have the "on" label on the same side as the "power". Isn't that wrong? From the "internal construction" image (left), I would say it is the other way round.
2. Is this 3-pins rocker an SPST switch? Why does it have 3-pins, whereas the second image (from the top of the post) only needs two for the (supposedly) same functionality? I guess it has to do with the ground, but I don't understand it.
3. Still in the 3-pins rocker, what prevents me from using the "power" and "ground" pins as accessories and put the power on the "accessory" pin in order to use the rocker as an SPDT switch? Would that be a correct SPDT switch?

Comment: Have you done any research on this at all. Like, do you know what SPDT stands for?

Comment: Google is your friend here. I remember a few years back when I was wondering what switch would suit one of my designs. I googled it. I had an answer in 5 minutes. Also, SPST stands for 'Single Pole Single Throw' and SPDT is 'Single Pole Double Throw'

Comment: Well, Google told me that apparently, a rocker is supposed to be single throw, but to me it either connects two pins or the other two. I don't see the difference with a 3-pins spdt, which is why I asked.

Comment: If your rocker has as many pins as an SPDT would, and behaves in the same way as an SPDT, then it is an SPDT. Putting an "On/Off" label on it won't magically turn it into an SPST.

Comment: If, in my understanding, my rocker has as many pins as an SPDT would, and behaves in the same way as I believe an SPDT behaves, but has a label suggesting it is an SPST, then either it is a wrongly-labelled SPDT, or there is something I don't understand. In either case it sounds rational to ask, IMHO (but I see people don't necessarily agree with that :-)).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SPST stands for Single Pole, Single Throw. SPDT stands for Single Pole, Double Throw. The 'Pole' is the number of circuits that can be controlled by the switch at any time. So a SP switch can only power one circuit at a time, a DP switch can do 2. The 'Throw' is how many 'on' positions it has (I am 90% confident on this, feel free to correct me).

So: An SPST switch you will only get an On/Off whereas if you had an SPDT switch, you could get a switch with 2 On positions and only have one circuit powered at any time, so you would try and find an 'On/On' SPDT switch.

Bonus answer: If you still wanted to use a switch for this, you could search for an 'On/Off/On' SPDT switch which will only power up 2 circuits (one at a time) but the middle position will be the 'Off' position, so gives you that 'break before make' feel when switching between your circuits.

Also, rocker switches can be SPST or SPDT. A quick search on any component site will give you all the options and descriptions you need.

Hope this helps

**EDIT**

1 - It isn't really 'wrong' as it doesn't really matter which side you use as ground and which you use as power if you are switching between the 2. Chances are, this switch you happened to get the diagram from has some form of indication (such as a 'red' part of the button to show ON) that means you would connect the power to this side.

2 - A 3 pin rocker is usually always going to be an SPDT switch, unless one of the pins is disconnected completely. Please see my previous answer for an explanation on how these switches work and you should get an understanding of it. And if you just want an on/off switch, all of these could do it, depending on how you wire it.

3 - Nothing stops you from using the middle pin as power and using either side to connect to different circuits. As I said in reply to your first question, you most likely happened to get a switch diagram of one with indicators on it, whereas you can buy blank looking ones too. Again, read my description and you can see that it doesn't actually matter, however, most of these datasheets and examples will have to show you something, they can't give an example and say 'it doesn't matter what you wire where' can they?

Again, I hope this has answered your (revised) question.

Comment: I am not sure I understand the spdt rocker idea. So you are saying that I have a rocker (saying "on/off"), but that maybe it was manufactured as an spdt (which I thought should say "on/on")? I don't understand why one would manufacture that =/.

Comment: That's not what I'm saying. It sounds from your description you already HAVE an SPDT switch. It has 3 terminals and as you said, one position connects the centre to the left and the other position connects the centre to the right. If you read by description of the switches, that shows it is an SPDT switch. Why do you think you have an SPST? Did you buy an SPST? Or did you just see a rocker switch and assume rockers are SPST?

Comment: I need to rephrase my question, sorry. I have zero vocabulary in electronics, so I am doing what I can with what I found online :-). From your comments, I have material to try to update my question in a constructive way!

Comment: Then what were you asking for? I thought I had managed to answer your question?

Comment: Ok, updated. Probably too much effort for such a down-voted and criticized question, but well... that's done. I hope it is clearer now. Maybe you can edit your answer to correspond to the new formulation.

Comment: I am not sure I understand your answer to "1". Are you saying that the labelling is not wrong and that pressing on the "on" side will power the circuit if the pins are connected according to their drawing?

Comment: Yes. If you wire it up according to the drawing, it will work that way. If you wire it up opposite, it'll work the opposite way. That particular switch may have had some form of indication that means it makes sense to wire it that way

Comment: I'm sorry I really don't get it :-(. Given the internal representation, if the switch is pressed on the left, then the power and accessory pins are disconnected, which means "off" to me. You are telling me that it actually means "on". So am I right to think that when the switch is pressed on the left, given the internal representation on the image above, then the power and accessory pins are disconnected and the accessory and ground pins are connected, or am I already wrong here?

Comment: Just stop overthinking it! That is the problem here. It is a simple switch. Ignore all the other stuff and just imagine it for what it is. A switch. You have a centre pin and a left hand pin, and a right hand pin. Switch it to the left and the centre pin is connected to the right hand pin. Switch it the other way and the opposite happens. Simple as that. Label it however you like and wire whatever you want to either pin. On/Off, Circuit 1/Circuit 2, whatever, it is still just a switch and it will behave the same as any other no matter what the labelling. That is there as a guide

Comment: I wasn't telling you it means on or off either way. I was just saying if you wire it up according to the drawing, it will work as the drawing suggests

Comment: And the drawing suggests that "on" is on the left, and "off" is on the right. There is nothing worse than a wrong tutorial. If I believe the tutorial is wrong, either I did not understand or the tutorial is wrong. I don't care about the drawing being wrong, but I want to know if it is or not. I guess I'll just assume it is wrong and hope for my understanding that it actually is :-). Thanks for your help!

Comment: I think it is probably right, depending on the type of switch

Comment: You can have visual indicators, such as a red side of the button to indicate ON. It could be that when switched to the right, the red ON part is on show, hence the word ON written next to it. Getting a random drawing from somewhere without checking what is it from can create these misunderstandings

Answer (score 3):

I think your diagrams are not exactly helping, in that "Power, Accessories, Ground" looks automotive to me and is probably appropriate to a SPST switch WITH A BUILT IN POWER ON INDICATOR LIGHT.
These have two terminals used to switch and a third one with an indicator light connected between it and one of the switch terminals. The wiring on these is not always intuitive and you should either do multi-meter checks to figure it out or read the datasheet. 
The trick is not to accidentally wire the switch contact pair across power and ground instead of power and load with the ground connected to the indicator lamp, a mistake that costs fuses.

Seriously, datasheets are your friend, far more then pictures from the web, they will be specific to the part you have and will include such things as current and voltage ratings, all things that you need to know about a specific part.

Get thee to Mouser/Digikey/Farnell and download some datasheets for switches, MUCH more informative then google images.